# Solve h2 vs oracle function to_char conversion

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper, h2

I have a table l$act, and it has an id which is a Number (sorry correction)

**I have the following h2 line:**

```
select char(act_table.id) lookup_val from l$act act_table
```

which runs fine in h2

**I also have  the following oracle line:**

```
select to_char(act_table.id) lookup_val from l$act act_table
```

which runs great in oracle.

Unfortunately I am running h2 in test and oracle in development.

I found cast (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)
which works for both. I tested it and it works in my base case.

However I googled around and found this http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_cast.htm states that I should not use cast on a number.

I'm looking for a better solution. Is there a way to handle this in the sql statement without using cast? I was hoping someone may have encountered this and know a function that works for both?

Is there a work around?

Currently it would appear based on the above link that if cast is the only option then I need to add extra padding to handle most numbers. But it's still labeled as "dangerous" and I'm not sure that I fully understand those risks.

I'd love to know what a better solution is if it exists, or what risks I run using cast with extra padding (I'm not sure that I fully understand the above link).

Comment: You say that you're running Oracle in development.  And `to_char` is an Oracle function.  But your title and tags say MySQL (a database that happens to be owned by Oracle Corp. that is completely different from the Oracle database).  If you are using Oracle, it's perfectly reasonable to use `cast` to convert the data type assuming that you don't want to do any formatting of the string that is produced.  Normally, when you're converting numbers or dates to strings, you care about the format of the string that is produced.

Comment: @JustinCave I'm sorry perhaps I'm mistaken let me check

Comment: @JustinCave sorry yes I am using Oracle. I only care to convert the long (id) to a string. I found cast but was concerned with the above link  http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_cast.htm

Comment: Is `id` a `long` (a depricated data type that is used to store large amounts of text data long superseded by `clob`) or is it a `number`?

Comment: @Justin Cave, sorry id is a **Number**

Comment: If `id` is a `long` then your `to_char` call would fail with an "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatype: expected CHAR got LONG" error.  If your `to_char` call works in Oracle, then `id` is not a `long`.

Comment: @JustinCave Sorry correction it is a Number

Comment: This shows, once again, that the tests you're writing are useless, because you're testing with a database that is not the one which will be used in production. So you'll have tests that pass although the code will fail in production, and tests that fail although the code will run fine in production. The cure is simple: use the production database for your tests.